# Getting BackgroundSession and daemon error when accessing an image with image_picker and then sending it to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have a simple app that lets users login and upload a profile image, however although the image is able to get selected and uploaded into Firebase storage, I am getting the following errors.

[core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""

image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality

BackgroundSession <405CA36E-031B-4916-B544-DC4991439A8B> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated